# Need help reading cursive text

Tags: character-identification

[image]

I've never learned cursive writing and I really can't read it.
This is what I see so far:
(*)为的漫步海边

无忧无虑 自由自在

慢悠悠的散步

实际上的(*)海
And does anyone know the name of the font?

Comment: 以為(presumed) ...环海 (around the sea = sea shore)

Comment: OK, thanks. That font makes no sense to me

Comment: Because these two sentences do not make sense, either read individually or together. You need help with the background material, but I guess this is a commercial advertisement.

Comment: it makes sense if you see them as captions for two pictures

Comment: It’s 行楷, the most commonly used style for handwriting.

Comment: It’s actually not missing. The contrast comes from what was pictured in mind ( 无忧无虑 自由自在 慢悠悠的散步) and what is actually experienced (what’s shown in the last picture). This type of contrast is widely seen in Chinese beyond those of the same structures of this particular example.

Comment: 自認的漫步海边,实际是環海(??), by foot or by boat? A sentence started with 自認 (perceived) should be finished with something contrary, which is missing here. It makes sense If (??) = 跋涉 (contrast to 漫步), but we don't know from the sentence or the pictures.

Comment: @r13 a very beautiful and romantic imagination vs. the not so beautiful and romantic scene and experience

Comment: 以为的漫步海边：无忧无虑 自由自在 慢悠悠的散步 the middle picture 
实际上的环海：the last picture.  
The contents after the colon are contrasted

Comment: @lilysirius 以為的漫步海边 - 无忧无虑 自由自在,  慢悠悠的散步 is the leading phrase, which is finished by 实际的環海(??), where is the contrast? The sentence is in the form of 以為{是)....实际上(不然).

Comment: @lilysirius What does 环海 mean? Why it is contrary to 漫步? Sorry, I really don't get it.

Comment: @r13 as I said, the last picture.  I don’t agree it has anything to do with 无忧无虑 自由自在, 慢悠悠的散步. The sentence comes WITH the picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136327/discussion-between-lilysirius-and-r13).

Comment: @lilysirius The sentence does not make sense, and the pictures do not help either. If you can clarify my doubt and wish to make your point, you can start a "chat", and I'll be notified.

Comment: @r13 I replied in the link you provide quite a while ago

Comment: This is posted on "chat":  环海 means looping around the seashore, which can be carried out in a relaxed manner - 环海漫遊, which is not much different than 漫步海边. Since we don't know what the author was trying to promote/sell, everybody would have guessed what does 漫遊 mean before being able to picture a scene in the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [行楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-cursive_script) format, which is my favourite font when I do hand writing because I'm too lazy to write [正楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) haha.

**If you want to learn proper hand writing, start with 正楷!**  You can later make smoother transition to 行楷 once you can write faster.

The two characters are [以](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%BB%A5) and [环](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%8E%AF)

Answer (score 1):

以为的漫步海边
无忧无虑  自由自在
慢悠悠的散步
实际上的环海
The above are the corresponding characters, as to the font, it is quite hard to determine. You can try to figure it out with word.